# Uniqueness of a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

If I know that a subgroup of a finite group is a normal subgroup, is this condition sufficient to state that it is unique?
I think that is sufficient thanks to Sylow's theorems, but in any exercises I've found that I must prove it is unique also if I already know it is normal.

Comment: What do you mean by unique here?

Comment: @Mark, I mean that I can't find other subgroups of the same order.

Comment: You should make that clarification by editing the body of the Question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no, there might be other subgroups of the same order. As an easy example, look at $\mathbb{Z_2}\times\mathbb{Z_2}$. It has $3$ distinct subgroups of order $2$, obviously all are normal. (since the group is abelian)

Now, specifically for Sylow subgroups it is true that a Sylow subgroup of a specific order is unique if and only if it is normal. It indeed follows from the second Sylow theorem which says that each two $p$-Sylow subgroups of a group $G$ are conjugate to each other.

Comment: so it's true only for the Sylow subgroup and not true for subgroups of Sylow subgroups?

Comment: Yes. For Sylow subgroups it is always true. In the general case the subgroup might not be unique.

Answer (score 1):

No. An example would be $G=C_2 \times A_4$. The first factor is a normal subgroup isomorphic to $C_2$, but $G$ has other subgroups of order $2$ (inside $A_4$) that are not normal.

Comment: what do you mean with $C_2$?

Comment: The cyclic group of order $2$.

Answer (score 0):

If a subgroup $H$ has an order that is unique, then $H$ must be normal, even characteristic.